# Why is my PATH ignored?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, path, osx-elcapitan

Although my Unix PATH includes `/Library/TeX/texbin` this component of my PATH appears to be ignored. For example, when I try

```
pdftex --version
```

I get

> -bash: pdftex: command not found

while

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdftex --version
```

works as expected.

Similarly,

where -a pdftex

gives no results.

My PATH is built from two sources: `/private/etc/paths`, which contains

```
/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/Rax/bin
```

and two additional files in `/private/etc/paths.d/40-XQuartz`, and `/private/etc/paths.d/TeX`, which contain, respectively

```
/opt/X11/bin
```

and

```
/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Together these 3 files result in the expected PATH

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

All the entries in the other directories are found as expected (inclusion those in `/opt/X11/bin`) but the last entry appears to be ignored (at least when locating executables).

Why is part of my PATH being ignored? How do I ensure that it is not, so that executables there are found as expected?

---

OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Presumably `which pdftex` yields "No pdftext in path"? This would rule out the slightly obscure possibility of something by that name in one of the directories earlier in your path that's borked in an obscure way.

Comment: Have you already tried this? `hash -r`

Comment: Are there any nonprinting characters in $PATH? Try `printf "%q\n" "$PATH"` and see what that shows.

Comment: @ChrisKitching: `which -a pdftex` yields nothing at all.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: `/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin\\` — note the final `\\`.

Comment: @Cyrus: How long are "remembered locations" (for `hash`) remembered?

Comment: Looks like there's a space at the end of $PATH, which it will treat as part of the filename. Check /private/etc/paths.d/TeX to see if there's a stray space in there.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Fixing that seems to remedy the problem. That'll be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got sorted out in the comments, but I'll post as an answer for the record: the problem was due to an invisible character in the `PATH`, that was being interpreted as part of the actual directory name. Specifically, it was a space at the end, but you could get the same effect from a number of other invisible characters. (I was actually guessing that one of the files in paths.d was in DOS/Windows text format, and had a carriage return at the end of the line.)

To make invisible characters more visible, you can use `printf` or `cat -vet`:

```
$ printf "%q\n" "$PATH"
/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin\ 
$ echo "$PATH" | LC_ALL=c cat -vet
/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin $
```

Note the `\` at the end of the `printf` output -- it's actually followed by a space, but you have to infer that -- and the space before the `$` in the `cat -vet` output. BTW, it's very important to put the reference to `$PATH` in double-quotes, since without them the space would've been trimmed.

If it had been a carriage return instead, here's what it would have looked like:

```
$ printf "%q\n" "$PATH"
$'/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin\r'
$ echo "$PATH" | LC_ALL=c cat -vet
/Users/Rax/.cabal/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Rax/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin^M$
```

In this case, `printf` shows the carriage return as `\r` (and wraps the whole thing in `$' ... '` to indicate that escapes should be interpreted), while `cat -vet` shows it as `^M`.