# Why is PATH on mac not working?

Tags: php, bash, macos

I installed a newer version of php, and tried to use it in Terminal. (GNU bash, version 4.4.12)

However the wrong php is getting executed.

`/usr/local/bin` is my first path in the path env-var. and there is no invisible chars like in [Why is my PATH ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829803/why-is-my-path-ignored)

```
printf "%q\n" "$PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
```

Running `which php` says `/usr/local/bin/php`, but running `php -v` gives the same version as `/usr/bin/php -v` (in my case 5.6.28).

I expected `php -v` to give the same version as `/usr/local/bin/php -v`(in my case 7.1.2).

Why doesn't it respect my PATH-setting, and is there some other way to  make `php` run `/usr/local/bin/php`?

Comment: This looks relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746240/in-bash-which-gives-an-incorrect-path-python-versions

Comment: have you tried 'hash -r' after updating your PATH? See https://superuser.com/questions/999439/when-to-rehash-executables-in-path-with-bash

Comment: never used `hash -r`, guess I have only had OS that done that for me when installing new software, or didn't use a cache. Shouldn't `witch` read from the cache then? `which` seams kind of unuseful if its answer may not be true.

Comment: That's why Bash has a built-in `type` which you should use instead.  `which`, like `echo -e`, is unforunately still popular in spite of 20+ years of well-known issues.